# How to connect to remote mysql using sqlyoug or heidisql

Tags: mysql, sqlyog, heidisql

I have mysql installed in unix box i want to connect that using sqlyog.
Usually i can connect through putty as below.

`login as : root`

`root@IP's password:: xxxxx`

`[root@somealiasname ~] mysql -u root -p`

`Enter password :`

`mysql>`

### How to Connect this mysql using sqlyog or heidisql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQLyog you can specify the connection details in the Connection manager dialog. The screenshot will be helpful for you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but if it is from RDP server i am unable to connect.